# How can I remove a blank space on my website?

Tags: html, css, overflow

There is a gap or blank space at the right side of my web page and I cannot manage to remove it. I don't know why it appears, I have look on all the elements of the page but nothing seems to be occupying that space.

You can go to the page so you can see what I mean, and also you can see all the source code: www.iot3k.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following problem can be overcome by doing:-

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Doing this you will hide the excess content along the x-axis.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In general when ever you have similar problem you just have to click f12 and go to mobile view or what ever view then you just have to click on the mouse within border icon then you just have to hover mouse on your page and it will show you what is making the problem.

in your case : 
you have to resize the images .

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.